# Constructing a sparse subgraph of original weighted undirected graph with approximation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In Kruskal's algorithm, we sort edges from least weight to greatest weight and add the edge if and only if both endpoints are in different connected components in current iteration.

Now the question is follows: Our goal is to construct a subgraph in a connected weighted undirected graph such that the distance between any two vertices in the new graph are at most twice of that in the original graph. Also, we want to make the graph sparse.

Some time ago my instructor said we can use the following algorithm: We iterate edges from least weight to greatest weight like Kruskal's and add the edge if and only if both endpoints are not connected or current shortest distance between the two vertices are strictly greater than twice of the edge weight. (We assume all edge weights are strictly positive, and distance is the sum of weight of edges on that path as usual)

I know how to show this new graph has the property that the distance between any two vertices in the new graph are at most twice of that in the original graph. The question is, how to show when $n$ goes to infinity, let $l(n)$ be the maximum **number** of edges selected by the algorithm among all graphs with $n$ vertices and all possible (strictly positive) edge weights. Show $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{l(n)}{n^2} = 0$. That is, the graph would be way much sparse than complete graph. Does anyone have good reference to this problem?

**Edit**: Thanks for pointing out! Looks like the argument is incorrect. I've got another question, that's change twice into 5 times. So the algorithm becomes We iterate edges from least weight to greatest and add the edge if and only if both endpoints are not connected or current shortest distance between the two vertices are strictly greater than **5 times** of edge weight. Our goal is to construct a subgraph in a connected weighted undirected graph such that the distance between any two vertices in the new graph are at most **5 times** of that in the original graph. We define $l(n)$ the same and show $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{l(n)}{n^2} = 0$.

Looks like the following lower bound argument doesn't quite generalize to 5 times. Consider a complete 5-partite graph. It doesn't have to be the case where we'll choose an edge between two parts, because 3-edge path doesn't have to be more expensive than 5 times the weight of an edge. Any ideas on that problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the limit is not $0$: the value of $l(n)$ is always $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$, the number of edges in a balanced complete bipartite graph.

To see that we can never do worse, note that the graph this algorithm constructs is always triangle-free: we will never add an edge between two vertices that are already connected by a path made up of two cheaper edges. By Mantel's theorem, every triangle-free graph has at most $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ edges.

To achieve this worst case, suppose that all edge weights are nearly the same: all of them are in the interval $[1,1.5)$. Then, even for the most expensive edge, twice its weight is still going to be cheaper than the cheapest $3$-edge path. So the only reason we would ever skip an edge is when adding it would create a triangle: when it's already connected by a $2$-edge path.

If the edge weights on $K_n$ are chosen so that the $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor $ edges on some $K_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \lceil n/2\rceil}$ subgraph are cheaper than all the edges outside it, then these will be considered first - and the graph we build at the end will *be* the complete bipartite graph. Therefore, $l(n) = \lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Looks like my argument was incorrect. I've got another question, that's if we change twice into 5 times, we define $l(n)$ the same and if we can show $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{l(n)}{n^2} = 0$ I’ve just edited my problem to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Now it becomes true (even with 3 instead of 5). You can just show that the graph that you output has no cycles of length 4, and hence O(n^1.5) edges. Say see this:https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.11601

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem right. Consider complete graph $K_{2n}$ in which each edge in some bipartite subgraph $K_{n,n}$ receives a weight 1, while all other edges have weight 1.1. Then the algorithm you describe will produce $K_{n,n}$ as an output which has $1/2$ of all original edges.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Looks like my argument was incorrect. I've got another question, that's if we change twice into 5 times, we define $l(n)$ the same and if we can show $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{l(n)}{n^2} = 0$ I’ve just edited my problem to make it clearer. Thanks!